Command line to open list of files in as many buffer viewports
When I use a command like as:
vim file1 file2 file3 ...

file1 is opened and I can navigate with :next and :previous
I would like all the files listed to be opened each in a different buffer viewports (windows in vim terminology).

:h -o, :h -O, :h -p :)

@ChristianBrabandt: ah good! Thanks, I had searched for "buffer" in the man page, and when phrasing my question and remembering the view of a buffer is actually called window, I didn't realise that was why I had found nothing! Lazy me.

$ vim --help, even.

Where possible, I recommend getting used to buffers, :args, and splitting windows as needed.

Answer
To open files in horizontally split windows, you can use the -o flag.
To open files in vertically split windows, you case use the -O flag.
To open files in separate tabs, you can use the -p flag.
Usage
Simply specify one of the flags like this:
vim -p file1 file2 file3 ...

or
vim file1 file2 file3 ... -p

Note
The -O help says

If both the -o and the -O option are given, the last one on the command line determines how the windows will be split.

This also applies to the -p flag as well, though that isn't mentioned in the help. That is, vim -o -O -o -o -p -O -p will behave the same as vim -p.
